# Is this still a parabaloid (even though it's very squished)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I had input this equation: $12\left(x+2\right)^2+y^2$ and I got a really flat parabaloid. I'm just curious if there's a special name or the like for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's an [elliptic paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid). By definition, $H\subseteq \Bbb R^3$ is an elliptic paraboloid if and only if there are $a,b>0$ such that $H$ is congruent to the locus $$\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\,:\, z=\frac{x^2}a+\frac{y^2}b\right\}.$$

Yours has $a=\frac1{12}$, $b=1$ and the isometry $\Phi(x,y,z)=(x+2,y,z)$.

$H\subseteq \Bbb R^3$ is a hyperbolic paraboloid if and only if there are $a,b>0$ such that $H$ is congruent to the locus $$\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\,:\, z=\frac{x^2}a-\frac{y^2}b\right\}$$